# All the values of $\cosh (\log 2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-functions

What are all the values of $\cosh(\log2)$?  This is problem IV.9.1 in *Complex Function Theory* by Sarason.

I know that
$$
\cosh(z)=\frac{\exp(z)+\exp(-z)}{2}.
$$
I also know that 
$$
\log(2)=\ln2 + 2\pi n i
$$
with $n$ an integer.  Thus 
$$
\cosh(\log(2))=\frac{\exp(\ln2 + 2\pi n i)+\exp(-\ln2 - 2\pi n i)}{2}\\
=\frac{2 \exp(2\pi n i)+(1/2)\exp( -2\pi n i)}{2}\\
=\frac{2 + 1/2}{2}=\frac{5}{4}
$$
I feel as though I am missing something because there should be a multiplicity of such values.

Comment: Whatever $\log 2$ means it should have the property that $\exp(\log 2) = 2$. So you're fine.

Comment: If you start with some $z,$ and find $e^z$ and $e^{-z},$ but then you change $z$ by adding $2 \pi i,$ then $e^z$ and $e^{-z}$ stay exactly the same. It would be different if you had $\cos z$ instead of $\cosh z,$ as then the change by $2 \pi i$ does have an effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Qiaochu Yuan.

Comment: And thank you too, @Will Jagy.